# Tiling a rectangle with squares

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, proof-explanation, rectangles

I read this article (images below) about tiling a rectangle ($x \times 1$, $x$ is irrational), and I can't quite get the part where it says "it's easy to see".

I understand that we need to prove that $v(R)=\sum_{i=1}^n v(Q_{i})$.

But why is it simple that $v(R) = v(B)$?

And why is it simple that $v(Q_{i})=\sum v(B)$?

Thanks,

Sam

[Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQEjl.jpg)

[Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OKBF.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Consider *all* the rectangles formed after you extend the edges of the squares $Q_i$, in the figure below I highlight three of them and label them with their side-lengths

$$
B(a_i,b_j): ~\mbox{rectangle with width} ~a_i~ \mbox{and height} ~b_j
$$

[image]

What is important to realize here is that

$$
\sum_k a_k = a_R = 1 ~~\mbox{and}~~~ \sum_k b_k = b_R = x \tag{1}
$$

With this in mind

\begin{eqnarray}
v(R) &=& f(a_R)f(b_R) \\
&\stackrel{(1)}{=}& f\left(\sum_k a_k\right)f\left(\sum_l b_l\right) \\
&\stackrel{f~{\rm is linear}}{=}& \left(\sum_k f(a_k)\right) \left(\sum_l f(b_l)\right) \\
&=& \sum_{k,l} f(a_k)f(b_l) \\
&=& \sum_{k,l} v(B(a_k, b_l)) \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Or in the notation of the paper

$$
v(R) = \sum_B v(B) \tag{3}
$$

Same argument can be applied to one individual square $Q_i$, but now $B$ only runs on the rectangles spanned by $Q_i$

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer!